Strict Transport Security Not Enforced fixed in IIS but still insecure
I configured HSTS in HttpResponseHeaders giving value as maxtime = 31536000 but still showing insecure popup in URL and using HTTP
given name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" in HTTP Response Headers.

Are you using http or https url? Could you share the snapshot if the logs you capture from the browser or any tool like fiddler. Which kind of application are you using asp.net core or something else?
